# How to iterate Flux with nested list of elements in Spring web flux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

There are nested list of elements that need to be iterated and provide the response data in the same hierarchical manner:

```
{
   
    "bank": [
        {
            "bankTitle": "bank1",
            "bankNumber": 1,
            "branch": [
                {
                    "branchTitle": "branch1",
                    "branchNumber": 1,
                    "city": [
                        {
                            "cityName": "city1",
                            "cityNumber": 1,
                            "user": [
                                {
                                    "userName": "user1,
                                    "userNumber": 1,
                                    "accounts": [
                                        {
                                            "accountName": "account1",
                                            "accountNumber": 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "accountName": "account2",
                                            "accountNumber": 2
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
        
    ]
}
```

We are sending above payload and on the basis of that need to create data in the same hierarchical way. Is there better way to iterate these nested List of elements in flux.

Comment: I tried with Flux.fromStream(banks().stream())
     .concatMap() but its returning duplicate data for bank list.

Comment: It's unclear what could be a problem with such a simple task. Can you give some examples of what you?